# Can I check my HTML snippet has only one top-level node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm testing a helper method, and have turned the snippet of HTML it produces into a Capybara node (with `node = Capybara::Node::Simple.new(html)`.

Can I check that the HTML contains only the top-level node I expect? That is, if I expect my HTML to be of the form:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="part-a">A</div>
  <div class="part-b">B</div>
</div>
```

... how can I verify that there is a top-level node (which is a `div.foo`), **and** that that node has no siblings?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling, I worked this out. `Capybara::Node::Simple.new()` wraps the snippet in a simple `<html><body>` pair. That means the following works:

```
# Check that the body has only one direct child
expect(node).to have_css('body > *', count: 1)

# Check that the expected node exists (and hang on to it for subsequent testing)
foo = node.first('body > div.foo')
expect(foo).not_to be_nil
```